# Merge Cells in a table using Delphi (XE4) and Word_Tlb

Tags: delphi, merge, ms-word, cells

I have inherited an application which works but I would like to add to it. What I would like to do is merge from the first to the 4th or 5th Cell on the 2nd Row. The template has been created in word and by using bookmarks the application replaces those words with information from the program. The 2nd row(technically 3rd but I am ignoring the header) only uses 2 of the possible 6 cells with the first cell being mostly text thus making it barely readable. It replaces the bookmarks on a row to row basis. The table is part of the template and not made via the code.

An issue is it is using Word_TLB which I am not accustomed to and have searched around for a couple of days for a valid fix to my problem. The closest I have gotten is merging all the cells on the row.

Anyways I will put some code snippets with regards to the what I think is relevant and can always update with more background code if needs be.

Variables used in the function (In the event I am missing something obvious)

```
var
  FColumns : TStringList;
  MSTables : ITables;
  MSTable  : ITable;
  MSRow, MSRow2    : IRow;
  MSCell   : ICell;
  MSCell2  : ICell;
  C        : Integer;
  TRow     : IRow;
  OleRow   : OleVariant;
  OleCell  : OleVariant;
begin
  for C := 1 to MSRow.Cells.Count do // Add the text  on a cell by cell basis
  begin
    MSCell := MSRow.Cells.Item(C);
    FColumns.Add(MSCell.Range.Text);
    MSCell := Nil;
  end;
```

Here is where the actual row is filled. The previous section just adds the data does none of the replacing yet.

```
if qSchedule.FieldByName('IQOQ').AsBoolean then
begin
  MSRow2 := MSTable.Rows.Item(3);
  OleRow := MSRow2;
  OleCell := MSRow2.Cells.Count;
  TRow := MSTable.Rows.Add(OleRow);
  DoRow(FColumns2,TRow);
  TRow.Range.SetRange(0,1); // Range set to get first and second cell to merge
  TRow.Range.Select; //Select the set range
  MSRow2.Application.Selection.Cells.Merge; //How I tried to merge specific cells
  TRow := Nil;
end;
```

DoRow is where the row gets replaced with regards to bookmarks... If it finds the bookmarks then it switches the text.

This approach does not seem to be working. I think it is because it is the range of the row, however I am unsure of how to get from one cell to another so that I can merge everything in between.

If I just do TRow.Cells.Merge that method merges all the cells on the row.

Comment: Removed more of the redundant data. Not sure how easy it will be for me to replicate this problem in another project, though I could give it a go. Reluctant to remove all the variables used as I guess it could give me the information needed to actually merge cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following (tested with D7 and Word2007) will help.

It shows how to create a Word table entirely in code, and then merge a range of cells in the
table's 2nd row.  It's deliberately a bit long-winded, for tracing purposes.
Your immediate problem may simply be that Merge() needs to be called on the starting cell of the span to merge, and it needs to be passed as an argument, the cell to finish merging on.

Even if the following doesn't completely solve your problems, you're welcome to use the following code to illustrate the remaining problem, rather than your "live" code.

Incidentally, the only reason I used late-binding in the code below is because it is recycled from an earlier answer of mine.  For future reference, when you get stuck on something like this, its actually easier to try and do what you're after using early binding (i.e. using the COM objects in the TLB import file, because you find out during compilation whether you're invoke the correct method on the correct object and supplying the correct arguments.  The downside is that you have to supply all arguments where the late-bound equivalent might allow you to supply only some of them, e.g. the early-bound version of Documents.Open requires 12 arguments, all of which need an OleVariant to be passed.

Another point is that the normal way to tackle something like merging cells from scratch is to record a Word macro and see how that does it.  Usually, that can be easily translated into Delphi automation code  The macro I recorded was an exception.  Translating it into Delphi resulted in an "interface not supported" exception because the macro called Merge on a range selection, which the COM object doesn't seem to support.

```
procedure TForm1.CreateTable(Rows, Columns : Integer);
var
  MSWord,
  Document,
  Table,
  Selection,
  Range,
  Cell,
  StartCell,
  EndCell : OleVariant;
  ARow,
  AColumn: Integer;
  RowIndex,
  ColIndex : Integer;
  S : String;
begin
  try
    MsWord := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');
  except
    try
      MsWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
      MsWord.Visible := True;
    except
      Exception.Create('Error');
    end;
  end;

  Document := MSWord.Documents.Add;
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Size := 22;
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Bold := true;
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText(#13#10);
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText('This should be center-aligned');
  MSWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphCenter;
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText(#13#10#13#10);
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Size := 12;
  MSWord.Selection.Font.Bold := False;

  Table := MSWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add( Range:= MSWord.Selection.Range, NumRows:= Rows, NumColumns:= Columns, DefaultTableBehavior:= wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= wdAutoFitFixed);

  try
    for ARow := 1 to Rows do begin
      for AColumn := 1 to Columns do begin
        Cell := Table.Cell(ARow, AColumn);
        RowIndex := Cell.RowIndex;
        ColIndex := Cell.ColumnIndex;
        Caption := IntToStr(RowIndex) + '/' + IntToStr(ColIndex);
        Range := Cell.Range;
        Range.Select;
        if Odd(AColumn) then
          Range.Font.Bold := True
        else
          Range.Font.Bold := False;
        S := Format('Row: %d, col: %d', [RowIndex, ColIndex]);
        MSWord.Selection.Range := Range;
        MSWord.Selection.TypeText(Text := S);
      end;
    end;

    StartCell := Table.Cell(2, 1);  // Put a breakpoint here, switch to Word, then single-step
      // to see what happens
    EndCell := Table.Cell(2, 1 + 3);
    StartCell.Merge(EndCell);
  finally
    Document.Close(SaveChanges := False);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateTable(3, 5);
end;
```

You asked in a comment about early v. late binding.  That's a bit too big a topic to squeeze into
this answer, but essentially they are two different ways of interacting with objects inside another application (or in a DLL).

Later binding is where you interact with them using variants.  Delphi's automation support hides 
most of the details of interacting with these external objects behind its automation support via
late binding.  To be automatable in this way, the external application has to surface IDispatch 
interfaces.  Late binding usual starts with a call to CreateOleObject, to get hold of a reference to a top-level automation object in the external application.

Late binding is easy to do, but equally easy to get wrong, because the details of the interface to
the external object is hidden behind the variant(s) you use  with it and the Delphi compiler
can't use its type-safety to protect you from yourself.

Early binding means using the raw interfaces the object exposes.  You normally do this via the code
in the TLB import file which contains Object Pascal definitions of the interface methods 
and functions, which enables the compiler to enforce type-safety and syntactic correctness of your code.  So, it's safer and easier (in some ways) to do (or at least, get right), and can be a good bit quicker to, because it cuts out the layer of indirection (via variants) involved when using late-binding.

All this and a lot more about Delphi and COM/automation is explained in Eric Harmon's book about COM programming in Delphi, excerpted here:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=130494

Comment: The comment with regards merging led me to look at the ICell's closer. Which in turn allowed me to merge using the same technique you showed above. So for that I am grateful! Couple of follow up questions if you or someone else wouldn't mind answering them? What is early / late binding? It's a term I have come across a couple of times but not really understood what it means. By using a similar method to the merging, would I be able to say alter text size/font/bold/italics...etc? Thanks for your time and help, truly appreciate it!

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain a bit more about early v. late binding and to show in the code how to do some text effects like font size, bold and paragraph alignment.  Btw, as you'll probably have gathered, new SO users are a bit limited in what they can do (like only comment their own questions) until they've accumulated some reputation points.  If you "accept" an answer like mine by clicking the tick icon, it's mutually beneficial in that we both get some rep points.  Please don't feel obliged to accept my answer, if you get a better one, accept that.

Comment: Yeah I gathered that. Well your answer solved my problem and you gave me more than enough information to better understand about early/late bindings. Thank you very much for your time and help.